# Displaying Route Events using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, linear-referencing, route, events

In ArcMap you can add event table and route reference feature class and when you right click on event table there is an option to display route events.

I am struggling to find that option in ArcGIS Pro.  I know ArcGIS Pro has imported ArcMap functions with fancier names but it seems that this one is not included.

How can I display route events?

I do not want to create a actual feature class just to display route events.

Answer (score 2):

In ArcGIS Pro you have the [Make Route Event Layer (Linear Referencing)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/linear-referencing/make-route-event-layer.htm) tool which:

> Creates a temporary feature layer using routes and route events.
>
> When the temporary layer is used (displayed on a map, or used by
> another geoprocessing tool), dynamic segmentation is performed.